# Displaying about a Meg of Text in WPF

Tags: wpf, formatted-text

I have a barebones WPF app that has about a Meg of ASCII text to display.  I initially put a TextBlock in a WrapPanel in a ScrollViewer.  This correctly scrolled and resized when I resized the window, but it was super slow!  I needed something faster.

So I put the text in FormattedText, and rendered that using a custom control.  That was much faster, but it didn't resize.  So I made my custom control resize.  But it would ReDraw too many times a second, so I made it only redraw every 100ms.

Much better.  Rendering and Resizing still isn't great but it's much better than it was.  But I lost scrolling.

Eventually I need a solution that does a lot - but for now I'm trying to have a solution that does a little: show a mem of text, wrap, have a scrollbar, and be performant.  Eventually, I'd like it to scale to a gig of text, have colors inline, some mouseover/click events for portions of the text...

How can I make FormattedText (or perhaps more accurately, a DrawingVisual) have a Vertical Scrollbar?

Here's my FrameworkElement that shows my FormattedText:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Recall
{
    public class LightweightTextBox : FrameworkElement
    {
        private VisualCollection _children;
        private FormattedText _formattedText;
        private System.Threading.Timer _resizeTimer;
        private const int _resizeDelay = 100;

        public double MaxTextWidth
        {
            get { return this._formattedText.MaxTextWidth; }
            set { this._formattedText.MaxTextWidth = value; }
        }

        public LightweightTextBox(FormattedText formattedText)
        {
            this._children = new VisualCollection(this);
            this._formattedText = formattedText;

            DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
            DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
            drawingContext.DrawText(this._formattedText, new Point(0, 0));
            drawingContext.Close();
            _children.Add(drawingVisual);

            this.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(LightweightTextBox_SizeChanged);
        }

        void LightweightTextBox_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.MaxTextWidth = e.NewSize.Width;

            if (_resizeTimer != null)
                _resizeTimer.Change(_resizeDelay, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
            else
                _resizeTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(delegate(object state)
                {
                    ReDraw();
                    if (_resizeTimer == null) return;
                    _resizeTimer.Dispose();
                    _resizeTimer = null;
                }), null, _resizeDelay, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        public void ReDraw()
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    var dv = _children[0] as DrawingVisual;
                    DrawingContext drawingContext = dv.RenderOpen();
                    drawingContext.DrawText(this._formattedText, new Point(0, 0));
                    drawingContext.Close();
                }));
        }

        //===========================================================
        //Overrides

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount { get { return _children.Count; } }

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= _children.Count)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

            return _children[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For simple text a readonly `TextBox` is pretty good. For more complex matters you can use `FlowDocuments` (which can be hosted in a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`), `TextBlocks` also host [flow content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753113.aspx) but are not intended for larger amounts.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx):

> **TextBlock** is not optimized for scenarios that need to display more than a few lines of content; for such scenarios, a [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx) coupled with an appropriate viewing control is a better choice than **TextBlock**, in terms of performance. After **TextBlock**, [FlowDocumentScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.aspx) is the next lightest-weight control for displaying flow content, and simply provides a scrolling content area with minimal UI. [FlowDocumentPageViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentpageviewer.aspx) is optimized around "page-at-a-time" viewing mode for flow content. Finally, [FlowDocumentReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentreader.aspx) supports the richest set functionality for viewing flow content, but is correspondingly heavier-weight.

Comment: The [Optimizing WPF Performance article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613560.aspx) also says that FlowDocuments are the most resource intensive, moreso that TextBlock.  Granted I haven't tried it, but if it's supposed to be slower than TextBlock, and that was too slow...

Comment: @TomRitter: If there is no virualization going on that might very well be, i don't know though. Of course FlowDocuments are heavier in some ways but that does not mean that the displaying performance is also worse. Also as you intend to do more complex things later on you might end up making your control just as heavy as what is already there providing everything you need.